# Group APIs by parameter or tag or any different key

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have four types of API which needs to be grouped:

profileOne = path: `v1/profileOne/`

profileTwo = path: `v1/profileTwo/`

common = path: `v1/common` (could be accessible by both profiles)

But I also have some APIs for example:

`v1/test` and `v1/hello` which belongs to `profileOne` but different path.

**The only way where I could group `v1/profileOne` and `v1/test` and `v1/hello` is by path or package?**

```
    private static final String[] PROFILE_ONE_PATHS = { "/v1/profileOne/**", "/v1/test/**", "/v1/hello/**" };

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi profileOneApi(OpenApiCustomiser springCloudContractCustomizer) {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("profileOne").pathsToMatch(PROFILE_ONE_PATHS)
                .addOpenApiCustomiser(springCloudContractCustomizer).build();
    }
```

I'd like to add any key or property in my RestController and Group by it, is there any way?

My concern is avoid to every time a new endpoint of profileOne was added I have to change the configuration class.

I now that we have headers, consumes and produces options, but remembering I have common API which I need to exclude `v1/test` and `v1/hello` and `v1/profileOne`.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like the one you're asking for being supported by the Swagger-Core framework. Springdoc is built around Swagger-Core and thus doesn't have anything as such either to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this has been already answered [here](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1121):

- Define a `@Tag` on your operation level with the correct group name or in the `@Operation` level

  - If you don't want use the tags, then you have other `@Operation` attributes where you can add your key for search in part of the summary, description or any other relevant fields for your case.
- Then use it  for the filtering through `OpenApiCustomiser`

This is just a sample with tags, that you can adapt.

```java
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/sample1")
    @Tag(name = "profileOne")
    public void sample1(String toto) {
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/sample2")
    @Tag(name = "profileTwo")
    public void sample2(String toto) {
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi groupProfileOne() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .addOpenApiCustomiser(openApiCustomiserProfileOne())
                .group("profileOne")
                .packagesToScan("demo")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi groupProfileTwo() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .addOpenApiCustomiser(openApiCustomiserProfileTwo())
                .group("profileTwo")
                .packagesToScan("demo")
                .build();
    }

    private OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomiserProfileTwo() {
        return openApi -> openApi.getPaths().entrySet()
                .removeIf(path -> path.getValue().readOperations().stream()
                    .anyMatch(operation -> operation.getTags().contains("profileOne")));
    }

    private OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomiserProfileOne() {
        return openApi -> openApi.getPaths().entrySet()
                .removeIf(path -> path.getValue().readOperations().stream()
                    .anyMatch(operation -> operation.getTags().contains("profileTwo")));
    }
}
```